# What is the dimension of nonlinear term of Navier-Stokes equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the Navier-Stokes equation,
$\partial_t u+ u\cdot \nabla u= -\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p+ \nu \Delta u$,
Since the dimension of $\partial_t u$ is $\frac{L}{T^2}$, dimension of the  $u\cdot \nabla u$ must be $\frac{L}{T^2}$.Can anyone show me how?

Comment: Note that the dimension of $\nabla$ (which is $\frac{d}{dx})$ is $1/L$.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: As an alternative to Winthers comment, $\boldsymbol{u}$ is a velocity vector, so has dimensions length/time i.e $L/T$